# Sass Background Percentage Position

Tags: css, sass, semantics, squarespace

How do I stop Sass from performing a calculation on the following `background-position` declaration?

```
background: #000 url('/foo.png') no-repeat fixed center 110%/115%
```

---

Bug found. It has to do with SquareSpace servers and their compiling of pre-compiled CSS. The issue will have to be resolved on their end.

Comment: don't use shorthand?

Answer (score 2):

Use [string literals/interpolation, `#{"<string>"}`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```
background: #000 url('/foo.png') no-repeat fixed center 110%#{"/"}115%
```

As you've mentioned you might be passing the file through a LESS compiler, then you need to [escape the offending string using `~"<string>"`](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Escaping):

```
background: #000 url('/foo.png') no-repeat fixed center ~"110%/115%"
```

Comment: on Sassmeister I can't see any problem with the OP code: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/958d4a9a1fc591f0ca8326c40f46e368

Comment: @fcalderan It is possible that OP is using an older version of SASS

Comment: I've found the issue. I'm custom designing a SquareSpace page and they're recompiling all pre-compiled CSS as if it were LESS. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @RyanPrentiss Ah, if that's the case, you will need to use LESS way of escaping strings, i.e. `~"<string>"`

Comment: I compiled the CSS locally before uploading and the markup is fine. It's the actual compiled CSS SquareSpace is ruining by dividing the percentages.